# Python script causes blender to crash when executed

Tags: python, scripting

I just started automating some task in blender by using python scripts.

The script performs the following tasks:

1. creates a new material
2. puts the new material in the 1st material slot
3. Rename a batch of the same meshes
4. Unwraps the meshes

Im experiencing crashes everytime i run this script:

Im aware that the code might be very insufficient and can be improved.
Can any1 of you tell me why the script causes blender to crash?

Help would be much appreciated :-)!

````
bpy.data.objects["Window Panel"].select_set(True)

so = bpy.context.active_object

material = bpy.data.materials.new(name = "WindowPanel")
material.use_nodes = True

so.data.materials.append(material)

bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 8

bpy.ops.object.material_slot_move(direction='UP')
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_move(direction='UP')
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_move(direction='UP')
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_move(direction='UP')
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_move(direction='UP')
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_move(direction='UP')
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_move(direction='UP')

bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 0
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()

bpy.data.objects["Window Panel"].select_set(False)

for o in bpy.data.objects:

    if o.name.startswith("Window") and ("Panel") in o.name:
    
        o.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='MATERIAL')

for i, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects, 1):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.name = "WindowPanel" + str(i)

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.uv.lightmap_pack()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

for o in bpy.data.objects:

    if o.name.startswith("Window") and ("Panel") in ob.name:
    
        o.select_set(False) ```
````

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Comment: @Fring Why are you calling ```material_slot_move``` so many times (specially without checking if they exist)?This is the cause of your crash! If you want to set a material to the 1st slot you should use: check if the slot exists, add a slot if not, and then just set its material. ```if len(obj.material_slots)==0:bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()```, followed by ```obj.material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.materials.new("WindowPanel")```

Comment: @Secrop, Thanks alot. It works now!